# Accessing variable attribute information for axis labels in a ggplot2 function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for ways to increase data vis efficiency for a large dataset. I have created several functions using ggplot2 to that end.  Some of the resulting figures may be for distribution, consequently, I'd like them to have comprehendible titles and axis labels.  I'm thinking I can associate readable labels to each variable using `attr()`.  This way I do not have to rename the variables and deal with *long variable names including spaces*. I have succeeded in this when using ggplot's functions

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

# Set attributes
mt <- mtcars
attr(mt$mpg, "desc") <- "Miles per Gallon"   
attr(mt$cyl, "desc") <- "Number of Cylinders"


mt %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) +
  labs(x = attr(mt$cyl, "desc"),
       y = attr(mt$mpg, "desc"))
```

The above code behaves as I expect and returns a graph containing axis labels.  However, when I create a graphing function I can not figure out how to access the variable attributes.  Both of the following attempts succeed in creating the graph, however do not produce the axis labels

```
vis_1 <- function(.data, .x, .y) {
  .data %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = {{.x}}, y = {{.y}})) +
    labs(x = attr({{.data$.x}}, "desc"),
         y = attr({{.data$.y}}, "desc"))
}

vis_1(.data = mt, .x = cyl, .y = mpg)
```

and

```
vis_2 <- function(.data, .x, .y) {
  attr_x <- attr(.data$.x, "desc")
  attr_y <- attr(.data$.y, "desc")
  
  .data %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(x = {{.x}}, y = {{.y}})) +
    labs(x = attr_x,
         y = attr_y)
}

vis_2(.data = mt, .x = cyl, .y = mpg)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is [quoting](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) of the variables you are passing.

One option if you are willing to use `cyl` and `mpg` as quoted variables. The base `[` subset inside of `attr` will work fine, and in `ggplot` you can use `!!sym()`.

```
vis_2 <- function(df, x, y) {
  
  attr_x <- attr(df[,x], "desc")
  attr_y <- attr(df[,y], "desc")
  
  df %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(!!sym(x), !!sym(y))) +
    labs(x = attr_x,
         y = attr_y)
}

vis_2(mt, 'cyl', 'mpg')
```

---

A version passing unquoted variables. This solution uses `deparse(substitute(x))` for use in the `[` call and `!!enquo(x)` for use in `ggplot`.

```
vis_3 <- function(df, x, y) {
  
  # base quoting
  x_sub <- deparse(substitute(x))
  y_sub <- deparse(substitute(y))
  
  attr_x <- attr(df[,x_sub], "desc")
  attr_y <- attr(df[,y_sub], "desc")
  
  df %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes(!!enquo(x), !!enquo(y))) +
    labs(x = attr_x,
         y = attr_y)
}


vis_3(mt, cyl, mpg)
```

---

Yet another version using unquoted variables, this one using `{{` for `ggplot` and `deparse(ensym()` for `[`.

```
vis_4 <- function(df, x, y) {
  
  attr_x <- attr(df[,deparse(ensym(x))], "desc")
  attr_y <- attr(df[,deparse(ensym(y))], "desc")
  
  df %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_point(aes({{x}}, {{y}})) +
    labs(x = attr_x,
         y = attr_y)
}


vis_4(mt, cyl, mpg)
```